# How do I prevent control passing to the next Userform textbox?

Tags: vba, userform

I have a Userform with multiple Textboxes. All the Textboxes are in tab-order.

Each subsequent Textbox is back colored yellow to indicate to the user which is the next Textbox to complete.

If the Textbox Value is determined to be invalid I want the control to SetFocus back on that particular Textbox. However, control is automatically handed over to the next Textbox in the tab-order.

When I try to focus back on the required Textbox with the mouse, this fires an event on the next Textbox, which follows the rules of my program and requests the user to enter a valid value.

Below is a sample of two Textboxes, if the user fails to enter a first name I want the control to return to the tbxCustomerFirstName Textbox, however, the control is handed over to the tbxCustomerSurName Textbox, even though I've "tbxCustomerFirstName.SetFocus".

AstFlag = 2 means there has to be a valid value in the Textbox.
AstFlag = 1 means the Textbox value can be blank.

I stepped through the program and AstFlag does indeed = 2, and the set focus code is executed.

```
'====================================================================================
'
' Customer First Name
'
Private Sub tbxCustomerFirstName_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
Call tbxValues(3)
If tbxCancel = True Then
    Cancel = True
End If
If AstFlag = 2 Then
    tbxCustomerFirstName.SetFocus
End If
End Sub
'====================================================================================
'
' Customer Surname
'
Private Sub tbxCustomerSurName_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
Call tbxValues(4)
If tbxCancel = True Then
    Cancel = True
End If
If AstFlag = 2 Then
    tbxCustomerSurName.SetFocus
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you're setting `AstFlag` to some hard-coded value (why not use an enum?) on `_Enter`, and then verifying that flag on `_Exit`? That seems pretty frail...

Comment: I don't understand your usage of the `Cancel` parameter here. Setting it to `True` *cancels exiting the control* - that *should* be what you do *instead* of attempting to explicitly `.SetFocus` on the control being exited.

Comment: Also note that `If {bool-expression} = True Then` can be simplified to `If {bool-expression} Then`, and you probably want that `AstFlag` hard-coded value to be some named `Enum` constant instead.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the `Cancel` parameter to `True` when you mean to cancel *exiting the control*.

I don't know what your `tbxCancel` flag logic is, but...

```
If AstFlag = 2 Then
    theControlYouAreExiting.SetFocus
End If
```

Should be

```
If AstFlag = 2 Then
    Cancel.Value = True
End If
```

That will prevent exiting the control, so there's no need to `SetFocus` on anything. Now again I don't know what `tbxCancel` is supposed to be doing, but it doesn't look right.

In fact I would scrap all this painfully duplicated conditional logic, and implement some `Validate` method that returns `True` if the field is valid (and thus can be exited) and `False` if the field is invalid (and thus `Cancel.Value` must be `True` and focus remains on the control).

```
Cancel.Value = Not Validate(args)
```

Where `args` could be `theControlYouAreExiting.Tag`, and then you could use the controls' `Tag` property to hold the metadata you're likely currently hard-coding in `tbxValues`.

---

Ultimately the problem you're solving is going to create a mess no matter how you put it, because everything is happening in the form's code-behind: you want to separate the *View* (the form/UI) from the *Model* (the data it's manipulating).

The solution is to create a class module that represents your *model*. This *model* exposes a property that each control on your form manipulates, and then the model itself knows how to validate each property.

```
Option Explicit
Private model As CustomerModel

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set model = New CustomerModel
End Sub

Public Property Get CustomerModel() As CustomerModel
    Set CustomerModel = model
End Property

Public Property Set CustomerModel(ByVal value As CustomerModel)
    Set model = value
End Property

Private Sub tbxCustomerSurName_Change()
    model.Surname = tbxCustomerSurName.Text
End Sub

Private Sub tbxCustomerSurName_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Cancel.Value = Not model.IsValidSurname
End Sub
```

And with that you don't need to maintain flags and state switches to keep track of what the metadata is for the control you're in.

Comment: Thank you Mathieu, unfortunately, I am a programing dinosaur from a bygone age (young programmer in 1966 where you had to do everything yourself), only recently getting back into programming by teaching myself VBA. 
My first task is to Google enum! I haven’t taken any courses or read any books on VBA, just applied old-style logic to a modern programming language. Any suggestions?
I am now going to try and understand your suggestions. If acceptable to you, anything I am having difficulty with, I would like your advice on it.
Once again, thank you.